# mathplotlib is not updating animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, jquery-animate

I would like to animate points that are changing position in a 3D scatterplot.
At the first timepoint the points in the scatterplot have the coordinates from the entry scatter[0][1] and then at the next timepoint the coordinates are scatter[1][2] and so on.
I have already set up the animation function from mathplotlib but it doesn't update.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
from matplotlib import animation


fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)


ax.set_xlim3d([0, 100])
ax.set_xlabel('X')

ax.set_ylim3d([0, 100])
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

ax.set_zlim3d([0, 100])
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
    

scatter=[
 np.array([9.956433493781429,
        np.array([[50, 50, 50],
        [53, 54, 55],
        [50, 51, 50],
        [52, 52, 52],
        [50, 50, 52]])]),
np.array([10.189591392765704,
        np.array([[50, 50, 50],
        [73, 74, 75],
        [70, 71, 70],
        [72, 72, 72],
        [70, 70, 72]])]),
np.array([10.40490011215984,
        np.array([[80, 80, 80],
        [83, 84, 75],
        [80, 81, 60],
        [82, 82, 42],
        [88, 80, 52],
        [89, 81, 29]])])
]



x=scatter[0][1][:,0]
y=scatter[0][1][:,1]
z=scatter[0][1][:,2]



points, = ax.plot(x, y, z, '*')
txt = fig.suptitle('')

def update_points(num,x, y, z, points):

    for i in np.arange(0,len(scatter)):
        txt.set_text('time={:f}'.format(scatter[i][0]))
        new_x = scatter[i][1][:,0]
        new_y = scatter[i][1][:,1]
        new_z = scatter[i][1][:,2]

        points.set_data(new_x,new_y)
        points.set_3d_properties(new_z, 'z')

        return points,txt

ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_points, frames=len(scatter), fargs=(x, y, z, points))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The code needs to be like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
from matplotlib import animation


fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)


ax.set_xlim3d([0, 100])
ax.set_xlabel('X')

ax.set_ylim3d([0, 100])
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

ax.set_zlim3d([0, 100])
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
    

scatter=[
 np.array([9.956433493781429,
        np.array([[50, 50, 50],
        [53, 54, 55],
        [50, 51, 50],
        [52, 52, 52],
        [50, 50, 52]])]),
np.array([10.189591392765704,
        np.array([[50, 50, 50],
        [73, 74, 75],
        [70, 71, 70],
        [72, 72, 72],
        [70, 70, 72]])]),
np.array([10.40490011215984,
        np.array([[80, 80, 80],
        [83, 84, 75],
        [80, 81, 60],
        [82, 82, 42],
        [88, 80, 52],
        [89, 81, 29]])])
]



x=scatter[0][1][:,0]
y=scatter[0][1][:,1]
z=scatter[0][1][:,2]



points, = ax.plot(x, y, z, '*')
txt = fig.suptitle('')

def update_points(num,x, y, z, points):
    #for i in range(len(scatter)):
    print(num,range(len(scatter)))
    txt.set_text('time={:f}'.format(scatter[num][0]))
    new_x = scatter[num][1][:,0]
    new_y = scatter[num][1][:,1]
    new_z = scatter[num][1][:,2]
    print(new_x,new_y,new_z)

    points.set_data(new_x,new_y)
    points.set_3d_properties(new_z, 'z')

    return points,txt

ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_points, frames=3, fargs=(x, y, z, points))

plt.show()
```